# Кончилось или закончилось?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Например: "В холодильнике уже все (за)кончилось". Или: "Пьеса уже закончилась (кончилась, окончилась)"? Как тут грамотнее сказать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, оба слова кончилось и закончилось равноправны в вашем предложении. Но лучше употребить "закончить", потому что у этого слова всего [два значения](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), в отличие от "кончить", которое, благодаря всеми любимой порнографии, получило пошлый оттенок. Кроме того, оно имеет целых [семь значений](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C). У слова же "окончилась" [три значения](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C). Все эти три слова равноправны, но лучше употребить то, которое имеет более узкий смысл, подходящий в определенном примере.

Comment: Про холодильник я бы все же сказала "кончилось", тут другие смыслы (в частности, пошлый) не приходят в голову. Соответственно, "закончилось" звучит так, будто человек боится, что его поймут пошло.

Comment: Может, я такой наивный человек, но я, хоть убей, в возвратном глаголе (кончиться) никакого сексуального оттенка не вижу. А в невозвратном  - не хочу видеть! 

Валентин, Вы не обобщайте и за всех не говорите. Грубо выходит.

Comment: Слово "кончиться" можно понять в смысле "скончаться", поэтому лучше употребить  что-нибудь синонимичное.

Answer (score 1):

> > > "В холодильнике уже все (за)кончилось".

Варианты равноправны, хотя может от смысла зависеть.
Если означает просто "холодильник пуст", то скорее кончилось.
Если что-то типа "опять все сожрал", то может быть и "закончилось".
Субъективо "закончилось" предполагает какое-то целевое расходование.

> > > "Пьеса уже закончилась (кончилась, окончилась)"?

Тоже все варианты возможны. Но скорее "закончилась". "Кончилась" здесь скорее бы означало "время вышло". Ёще "кончилось" предпочтительнее в выражениях типа "Вот лето кончилось" по той же причине. А вот "окончить" сейчас всё более означает завершить процесс, курс - т.е. направленное действие. В возвратной форме встречается реже.

Answer (score 1):

Закончила школу - детство кончилось

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд это слова равнозначные, если не принимать во внимание специальное толкование. Наверно, можно взять за правило ориентацию на контекст, когда мы говорим о количественном или о том, что нельзя подсчитать — будь то время, протяжённость пространства и т.д. Закончила школу — это можно определить количественно, закончилось детство — нет. Контекст почти всегда важен. Иногда, заканчивается — усиливает конструкцию, а кончается — это всё таки нечто протяжённое. Например, заканчивается терпение и кончается терпение. В первом случае, заканчивается просто усиливает конструкцию и время всё таки можно примерно подсчитать — через тридцать секунд взорвусь. Заканчивается работа — конкретно, как таковая определена, а кончается работа — определена вообще, в общем смысле, не количественное. Когда ты заканчиваешь работу? В 17:00 — это конкретно, количественно. Далее, мы не знаем, где заканчивается Вселенная, и мы не знаем, где кончается Вселенная. В последнем случае мы не можем определить, где граница Вселенной вообще, тогда как в первом варианте это возможно определить, хотя всё же и примерно, на основе предыдущего опыта — примерно 46 миллиардов световых лет, это вычислено.

Разница между двумя этими словами — кончаться и заканчиваться — ускользающе мала, но, в зависимости от контекста — определённого количественно или качественно, всё же есть.

Answer (score 0):

"продукты в холодильнике закончились", "лето закончилось", почему "закончилось", а не "кончилось" ?
Потому что по смыслу лето еще вернется, то что периодически возвращается, то "закончилось"

Comment: А когда, к примеру, жизнь заканчивается, значит ли это, что она вернется?

Answer (score 0):

лично я вижу такую разницу: "на этом **заканчивается** футбольный матч", т.е. он кончился или закончился только что, но нельзя сказать "на этом **кончается** футбольный матч". "**кончается** футбольный матч" - это когда осталось ещё пару минут, но матч ещё не завершён.